PieCloudDB kernel parameter configuration
I was trying to deploy a PieCloudDB Database cluster within our local private cloud environment with 6 servers configured as follows:
CPU：128core，2GHz
Memory：1024GB
Data Disks：12*1.92TB SATA SSD

We are currently experiencing occasional network-related errors during use, and we suspect it might be an issue with the kernel parameter configuration. Could you recommend any optimal parameter settings?

Based on your configuration and considering that you are deploying in a private cloud environment to run PieCloudDB database, you can use the following kernel parameter settings. These parameter settings involve modifications related to system semaphores, networking, and memory. You can directly write the following parameters into the /etc/sysctl.conf file on all hosts and execute sysctl -p to apply the changes.
kernel.shmmax = 5000000000000
kernel.shmmni = 32768
kernel.shmall = 40000000000
kernel.sem = 1000 32768000 1000 32768
kernel.msgmnb = 1048576
kernel.msgmax = 1048576
kernel.msgmni = 32768

net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 80000
net.core.rmem_default = 2097152
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.optmem_max = 16777216
net.core.netdev_budget = 1200
net.core.somaxconn = 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=30

vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.swappiness = 0
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 10

fs.file-max = 4194303
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 16384
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 512
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 65536

